# Implement Retry Functionality for request api in Python without any library

Tags: python, api, exception, retry-logic, connectionexception

I am trying to build a vaccine availability project. I make a request every 4 seconds to check doses for a vaccine,

```
response = requests.get(https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByDistrict?district_id=770&date=)
```

At times I face exceptions of `Connection Error`. I want to add **retry functionality** to my code, I know there are many answers out there, but they are using the library. I want to **build my own retry functionality** to understand core mechanics and for fun.

Can anyone help with how it should be implemented?

Comment: If you want to *understand core mechanics and for fun* why don't you try?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to start and what all functionalities should I concern. Whether I should implement a class or not. If anyone can provide any demo code of workings I would be quick to understand....

Comment: Put the `requests.get()` call inside a try/except block, and if you get ConnectionError, try again.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Yes, I got it. I have simply placed my `function()` in except block with time.sleep(30). Thanks, Man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import time
def foo():
    try:
        response = response.get("some URL")
    # you can modify exceptions as per your choice
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(30)
        foo()
```